# finding particular word in a set of web pages issue

Tags: python, web-scraping

this code fetches the course links in the udacity website and searches each of the links to find the search word("computer vision").
if the search is found it will print that link.
but in my code it prints the links which doesn't contain the search word also.for some other search words(eg:python) it omits some urls containing the search word.
What may be the reason.

eg's of links which dont have the search term:
https://in.udacity.com/course/advanced-android-app-development--ud855

https://in.udacity.com/course/engagement-monetization-mobile-games--ud407
etc..

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import urlopen
page = requests.get("https://in.udacity.com/courses/all")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
courses = soup.find_all("a",class_='capitalize')
search_term = "computer vision"
i=1
for link in courses:
    site =urlopen("https://in.udacity.com"+link.get("href")).read()
    if search_term in site.decode():
        print("https://in.udacity.com"+link.get("href"))
```

Comment: What are examples of links which don't contain that term?

Comment: That's not a link...

Comment: https://in.udacity.com/course/engagement-monetization-mobile-games--ud407

Comment: The reason is that your function searches the entire HTML of the page, including parts which are not visible. If you view the source of that link and find the term "computer vision", it is in fact there.

Comment: @MarcusLim links added in the description

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of this problem because JavaScript code contain `search_term`.

You can try replace `urlopen().read().decode()` to `requests.get().text`.

```
site =urlopen("https://in.udacity.com"+link.get("href")).read()
if search_term in site.decode():
    print("https://in.udacity.com"+link.get("href"))
# to
site = requests.get("https://in.udacity.com"+link.get("href"))
if search_term in site.text:
    print("https://in.udacity.com"+link.get("href"))
```

`requests.get().text` just contain characters that showing on browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following but bear in mind it is also picking up Computer Vision from the navigation side bar.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = requests.get("https://in.udacity.com/courses/all")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
courses = soup.select('a.track-link')
search_term = "computer vision"

for link in courses:
    page = requests.get("https://in.udacity.com" + link['href'])
    soup = bs(page.content, 'lxml')
    if search_term in soup.select_one('html').text:
        print("https://in.udacity.com" + link.get("href"))
```

Comment: i tried your code by replacing courses = soup.select('a.track-link') as courses = soup.select("a.capitalize") [that is what i need].but facing the same issue.

Comment: why did you change the selector?

Comment: because i need to fetch the links in that class only

Answer (score 0):

and finally this code worked. it extracts all the text from the webpage and does the search in that text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib.request


def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

page = requests.get("https://in.udacity.com/courses/all")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
courses = soup.select('a.capitalize')

search_term = "computer vision"

for link in courses:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://in.udacity.com" + link['href']).read()
    if search_term in text_from_html(html):
        print("https://in.udacity.com" + link.get("href"))
```